# How can I simulate a click on a jQuery UI radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have some radio buttons

```
<div id="typeRadios">
    <input id="character_chartype_a" name="character[chartype]" type="radio" value="A" /><label for="character_chartype_a">A</label>
    <input id="character_chartype_a" name="character[chartype]" type="radio" value="B" /><label for="character_chartype_b">B</label>
</div>
```

that I turn into jQuery UI buttons

```
$("#typeRadios").buttonset();
```

What line of code can I use to simulate a click on one of the buttons? I've tried this

```
// here data.chartype equals "A"
$("input[value='"+data.chartype+"']").click();
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do it with the `label` element added by jQuery UI. Try:

```
$("label[for='character_chartype_"+data.chartype+"']").click();
```

Have a look at it here, in a controlled environment: http://jsfiddle.net/B3d4z/

Comment: @ben: I think I know the problem... updating my soltion now. The `label` 's `for` attribute matches the `input` 's `id` , not `value`

Comment: but... it does not fire an event when you simulate the click.  http://jsfiddle.net/XrCNj/  Ideas on how to fire the event?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [`select`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) event.

```
$("input[value='"+data.chartype+"']").select();
```

Comment: I believe that would work *if* it was just `input` elements, but with jQuery UI the `input` is hidden and the button recreated from a new `label` and a `span` , thus this won't work. I've tested it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="radioVote">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1"/><label for="radio1">ONE</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2"/><label for="radio2">TWO</label>
</div> 



$(document).ready(function(){

        $( ".radioVote" ).buttonset();

        $('[for^=radio]').click(function() {
            var theRadioElement = $(this).prev();
            alert("Button" + theRadioElement.attr('id') + " clicked. VALUE:" + theRadioElement.val());
        });

    });
```

This example shows how to get the ID and Value when you click on a label that belongs to a jQueryUI radio.

Happy coding :)