# Different outcome between a user clicking a jQuery UI button and using jQuery click() on it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, click

I have a form to create a Ruby on Rails object. A part of the form uses radio buttons to choose an attribute. I then use [jQuery UI to display the buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio), like so.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#typeRadios").buttonset();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="typeRadios">
    <input id="character_chartype_a" name="character[chartype]" type="radio" value="A" /><label for="character_chartype_a">A</label>
    <input id="character_chartype_b" name="character[chartype]" type="radio" value="B" /><label for="character_chartype_b">B</label>
</div>
</body>
```

This all works fine. I click a button, and then when the form is submitted the attribute is saved correctly.

The problem is, I need to be able to click one of the buttons programmatically. At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
// data.chartype = a
$("label[for='character_chartype_"+data.chartype+"']").click();
```

This works in the sense that visually the button appears clicked, but when the form is submitted, the attribute isn't saved. What is causing this behaviour? Thanks for reading.

EDIT: fixed typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should click the radio button directly like this:

```
$("#character_chartype_" + data.chartype).click();
```

It *does* click the button, you just need to tell jQuery UI to refresh it's visual state afterwards using [the `refresh` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#method-refresh), like this:

```
$("#typeRadios").buttonset("refresh");
```

So overall this should do it:

```
$("#character_chartype_" + data.chartype).click();
$("#typeRadios").buttonset("refresh");
```

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for that option a while back too

Answer (score 0):

1. an id has to be unique. just a c&p failure?
2. why not "click" the radio button directly?

```
$("#character_chartype_" + data.chartype).click()
```

Comment: Because it's jQuery UI - see this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593301/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-on-a-jquery-ui-radio-button

Comment: @YiJiang - Clicking the `<label>` wasn't the right solution :) jQuery UI provides a method for updating a programmatically changed selection :)